# Is it ok to use RewriteEngine in virtual host for PhusionPassenger?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, passenger

How could I get normal Rewrite rules in the virtual host work for Phusion Passenger?

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.google\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.google.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

I basically want any traffic coming to xyz2.google.com/abc to get redirected to www.google.com/abc

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I am using Apache together with Passenger, my apache config looks something like this:

```
<VirtualHost mysite.com:80>
    Redirect permanent / https://mysite.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine On
    ReWriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://mysite.com/$1 [NC,R,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

This works fine for me to redirect everything to https://mysite.com
Should work similar for you.

Answer (score 0):

In general yes. If you use the `PassengerHighPerformance` [setting](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#PassengerHighPerformance) for a location then you shouldn't use rewrite rules for that location.

Do check your version of passenger though, versions earlier than [2.1.1](http://blog.phusion.nl/2009/03/01/phusion-passenger-211-beta-released-thanks-sponsors/) weren't fully compatible with mod_rewrite